# Calendar program for C++ class has a day counting bug

Tags: c++

I am making a calendar program in C++ that determines the days of a month in any given year by counting the number of days between January 1st, 1753 all the way to the first day of the given month in the given year. It then divides this number of days by 7 to determine the "offset" that is used to figure out what day the first day of the month begins (example: since January 1st, 1753 is on a Monday, an offset of 2 means that the first day of the month will be on a Wednesday). I completed my code and ran it through several tests when I noticed a very strange bug. For the year 2000, the offset is one higher than it should be (February starts on a Wednesday instead of a Tuesday, etc). This problem doesn't exist in any other leap year, or year ending with "00". It is the only test I am failing, and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
//**********************************************************************
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getYear();
int getMonth();
int computeNumDays(int month, int year);
int computeOffset(int month, int year);
bool isLeapYear(int year);
void displayHeading(int month, int year);
void displayTable(int offset, int numDays);
/********************
* MAIN
*********************/
int main()
{
   int month = getMonth();
   int year = getYear();
   int offset = computeOffset(month, year);
   int numDays = computeNumDays(month, year);
   displayHeading(month, year);
   displayTable(offset, numDays);
   return 0;
}
/********************
*GETMONTH
*Prompts the user for a month number
*********************/
int getMonth()
{
   int month;
//Month number must be between 1 and 12
   cout << "Enter a month number: ";
   cin >> month;
//Displays an error message if the month is under 1 or over 12
   while (month < 1 || month > 12)
   {
      cout << "Month must be between 1 and 12.\n";
      cout << "Enter a month number: ";
      cin >> month;
   }
   return month;
}
/********************
*GETYEAR
* prompts the user for a year
*********************/
int getYear()
{
   int year;
   cout << "Enter year: ";
   cin >> year;
//Displays an error message if the year is less than 1753
   while (year < 1753)
   {
      cout << "Year must be 1753 or later.\n";
      cout << "Enter year: ";
      cin >> year;
     
   }
   cout << "\n";
   return year;
}
/********************
*COMPUTENUMDAYS
* For computing the number of days in a month, so we know where to count to when filling in
* the calendar
*********************/
int  computeNumDays(int month, int year)
{
int numDays; 
if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
   return numDays = 31;
else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
   return numDays = 30;
else if (month == 2 && (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
   return numDays = 29;
else if (month == 2)
   return numDays = 28;
}

/*********************
*COMPUTEOFFSET
*********************/
int computeOffset(int month, int year)
{
   int totalYearDays = 0;
   int totalMonthDays = 0;
//This counts up all the days between the January 1st of 1753 to January 1st of the users input
//year. Leap years are accounted for with the IF statements and the isLeapYear function
   for (int yearCount = 1753; yearCount < year; yearCount++)
   {
      if (isLeapYear(yearCount))
         totalYearDays += 366;
      else
         totalYearDays += 365;
   }
//The days of the month of the user input year are added up here. If the user inputs February(2),
//then it counts the days of each month in between and adds them up. 
   for (int monthCount = 0; monthCount < month; monthCount++)
   {
      if (monthCount == 1 || monthCount == 3 || monthCount == 5)
         totalMonthDays += 31;
      else if (monthCount == 7 || monthCount == 8 || monthCount == 10 || monthCount == 12)
         totalMonthDays += 31;
      else if (monthCount == 4 || monthCount == 6 || monthCount == 9 || monthCount == 11)
         totalMonthDays += 30;
//if the user input year is a leap year, then an extra day to February is added
      else if (monthCount == 2 && (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
            totalMonthDays += 29;
      else if (monthCount == 2)
            totalMonthDays += 28;
   }
   int offset = (totalYearDays + totalMonthDays) % 7;
   return offset;
}
/******************************************
* ISLEAPYEAR
******************************************************/
bool isLeapYear(int yearCount)
{
//Equation for determining if a year is a leap year or not
   if ((yearCount % 4 == 0 && yearCount % 100 != 0) || (yearCount % 400 == 0))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
/*************************************************
*DISPLAYHEADING
* This is where the Month Name and Year are shown
**************************************************/
void displayHeading(int month, int year)
{
if (month == 1)
   cout << "January, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 2)
   cout << "February, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 3)
   cout << "March, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 4)
   cout << "April, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 5)
   cout << "May, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 6)
   cout << "June, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 7)
   cout << "July, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 8)
   cout << "August, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 9)
   cout << "September, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 10)
   cout << "October, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 11)
   cout << "November, " << year << endl;
else if (month == 12)
   cout << "December, " << year << endl;

return;
}

/********************
*DISPLAYTABLE
*********************/
void displayTable(int offset, int numDays)
{
   //days of the week are displayed here
   cout << setw(4) << "Su" << setw(4) << "Mo" << setw(4) << "Tu"
      << setw(4) << "We" << setw(4) << "Th" << setw(4) << "Fr" << setw(4)
      << "Sa" << setw(2) << endl;
//WeekBreak counter will be used to add new lines for each week
   int weekBreak = 1;
   //This IF statement determines the number of days before the first of the month occurs,
   // as well as sets the weekBreak counter
   if (offset != 6 && offset >= 0)
      do
      {
         cout << setw(4) << "  ";
         offset--;
         weekBreak++;
      }    while (offset != -1);

      //The counter loop here begins putting in the dates, all the way from the first to
//the max number of days in the month
      for (int date = 1; date <= numDays; date++)
      {
         cout << "  " << setw(2) << date;
         weekBreak++; //weekBreak prevents us from putting more than 
                      //7 dates in a single week
         if (weekBreak == 8)
         {
            cout << "\n"; //once a week hits 7 dates(or 8 spaces), it moves on to a new week
            weekBreak = 1;
         }
      }
      //this puts an end to the calander, regardless if weekBreak limit is reached
      if (weekBreak >= 2 && weekBreak <= 7)
         cout << "\n";

}
```

It bothers me that it only seems to happen for the year 2000. I'm not sure what the cause could be, so I could really use some feedback.

Comment: I suggest that you [`#include <chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) and start reading about what that provides.

Comment: Recommendation: Back up what you've got and remove all of the user input. Replace it with hard-coded values that you know cause the error you're hunting. This reduces the cycle time of your experiments and gets everyone working on the same data set and hopefully the same bug.

Comment: Does your code take into consideration that years divisible by 100 are not leap years, but years divisible by 400 are?

Comment: I don't like `if-else-if` ladders.   Use an array of strings:  `char * month_names[] = { "none", "January", "February", "March", ..., "December"}; std::cout << month_names[month] << ", " << year << "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

To debug your code I wrote the following `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    for (int year = 1753; year <= 2021; year++)
    {
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
        {
            int offset = computeOffset(month, year);
            int numDays = computeNumDays(month, year);

            std::chrono::year_month_day date(std::chrono::year(year), std::chrono::month(month), std::chrono::day(1));
            std::chrono::weekday day{ std::chrono::sys_days(date) };
            int expectedOffset = ((day - std::chrono::Monday).count() + 7) % 7;
            if (expectedOffset != offset)
            {
                std::cout << year << "/" << month << " expected " << expectedOffset << " actual " << offset << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This confirms it is indeed only the year 2000 which is incorrect. This suggests its the handling of the leap year every 400 years which is incorrect.

As you have a function for calculating leap years the first thing to try is to use that rather than implementing the same code three times (implementing something 3 times triples the chances of creating a bug). Changing `computeNumDays` to:

```
    else if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year))
        return numDays = 29;
```

and `computeOffset` to:

```
        else if (monthCount == 2 && isLeapYear(year))
            totalMonthDays += 29;
```

fixes the bug.

The cause of the bug is actually the combination of 2 bugs:

1. in `computeOffset` `monthCount` starts from `0` not `1`.
2. the expression `monthCount == 2 && (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)` will always be `true` when `year % 400 == 0` is true. The intended expression was `monthCount == 2 && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))`

This causes the value of `totalMonthDays` to be 29 more than it should be for years divisible by 400, after `%7` this causes the result of `computeOffset` to be 1 higher than it should be.

By removing repetition your code can be greatly simplified:

```
int computeNumDays(int month, int year)
{
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        return 31;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        return 30;
    case 2:
        return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid month");
    }
}

int computeOffset(int month, int year)
{
    int totalYearDays = 0;
    int totalMonthDays = 0;
    //This counts up all the days between the January 1st of 1753 to January 1st of the users input
    //year. Leap years are accounted for with the IF statements and the isLeapYear function
    for (int yearCount = 1753; yearCount < year; yearCount++)
    {
        if (isLeapYear(yearCount))
            totalYearDays += 366;
        else
            totalYearDays += 365;
    }
    //The days of the month of the user input year are added up here. If the user inputs February(2),
    //then it counts the days of each month in between and adds them up. 
    for (int monthCount = 1; monthCount < month; monthCount++)
    {
        totalMonthDays += computeNumDays(monthCount, year);
    }
    int offset = (totalYearDays + totalMonthDays) % 7;
    return offset;
}

bool isLeapYear(int yearCount)
{
    //Equation for determining if a year is a leap year or not
    if ((yearCount % 4 == 0 && yearCount % 100 != 0) || (yearCount % 400 == 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of C++20 chrono to write the debug code. Fwiw, here's C++20 chrono (well pre-C++20 date.h) to print out calendars:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#calendar. A big advantage of the chrono-based code is that there's no loop to implement `computeOffset`. This functionality is found in `print_line_of_calendar_month`, `case 2`, `string(static_cast<unsigned>((wd-firstdow).count())*3, ' ')`. Or more concisely, just the sub-expression `(wd-firstdow).count()`. This computes the number of days from `firstdow` (Sunday) to the first day of the month.